# How to delete specific rows depending on a condition in power BI using power query/ m language

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, delete-row, m

I need to delete rows following 2 logics:

First: If the ID is the same and the date is further away then delete the row with the date further away

Second: If there are identical rows, keep only one

How can I achieve this in power query? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dataset as following, and you would like show only each unique with the earlier date:

[image]

Using Group by function can easily achiever such output with `min` as filter criteria

[image]

Here is the outcome, accept if help :)

[image]

Comment: In my specific case I needed a bit more data treatment but It ended up working perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Accept the answer if helping, thank you :)